# How can i read 10minutes intervel using pandas readcsv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have file which contains date and time i dont need the full readings I just only need reading on particular intervals and it in minutes Is it possible to read data only on particular intervals the intervel must be start from the first date and time here it is 2017-10-12 06:54:52 0.004 and i only need the next reading which is after 10 mins

```
  Tran        Tran        Vert        Vert        Long        Long        Geo   
              Peak        Freq        Peak        Freq        Peak        Freq        PVS   
  Time        in/s         Hz         in/s         Hz         in/s         Hz         in/s  
2017-10-12
06:54:52    0.004       N/A         0.012       4.0         0.006       N/A         0.012   
07:09:52    0.004       5.2         0.011       3.9         0.005       32          0.012   
07:24:52    0.004       8.0         0.025       9.7         0.007       8.0         0.026   
07:39:52    0.004       6.4         0.025       9.0         0.007       10          0.026   
07:54:52    0.005       >100        0.020       8.5         0.007       34          0.020   
08:09:52    0.006       8.0         0.014       7.8         0.006       16          0.014   
08:24:52    0.004       5.1         0.012       3.9         0.006       10          0.013   
08:39:52    0.004       6.2         0.012       6.4         0.006       6.0         0.012   
08:54:52    0.004       7.6         0.015       5.6         0.007       5.1         0.015   
09:09:52    0.003       10          0.011       6.1         0.006       32          0.012   
09:24:52    0.005       6.2         0.016       8.4         0.007       6.2         0.016   
09:39:52    0.004       7.8         0.012       9.5         0.007       9.8         0.012   
09:54:52    0.007       7.4         0.017       5.2         0.006       5.1         0.017   
10:09:52    0.005       5.7         0.013       6.6         0.006       16          0.014   
10:24:52    0.004       6.5         0.013       4.7         0.007       6.1         0.013   
10:39:52    0.005       8.0         0.017       10          0.007       6.0         0.017   
10:54:52    0.004       47          0.019       8.5         0.006       10          0.019   
11:09:52    0.005       7.4         0.016       9.1         0.006       7.8         0.016   
11:24:52    0.004       5.2         0.013       5.8         0.006       3.1         0.014   
11:39:52    0.006       8.5         0.013       10          0.010       4.3         0.013   
11:54:52    0.006       7.4         0.027       9.5         0.010       6.6         0.027   
12:09:52    0.003       51          0.011       2.6         0.006       32          0.011   
12:24:52    0.003       85          0.011       2.0         0.006       15          0.012   
12:39:52    0.005       12          0.018       7.5         0.007       5.3         0.018   
12:54:52    0.006       11          0.027       9.3         0.007       5.4         0.027   
13:09:52    0.010       18          0.016       6.1         0.007       12          0.017   
13:24:52    0.006       6.7         0.015       5.7         0.007       4.5         0.015   
13:39:52    0.004       11          0.018       7.6         0.007       5.1         0.018   
13:54:52    0.005       6.4         0.021       6.9         0.008       7.6         0.022   
14:09:52    0.005       6.0         0.014       5.0         0.006       7.5         0.015   
14:24:52    0.005       6.8         0.012       6.8         0.006       16          0.013   
14:39:52    0.007       8.3         0.016       6.6         0.006       7.4         0.017   
14:54:52    0.007       6.4         0.018       7.1         0.006       5.2         0.018   
15:09:52    0.005       8.5         0.012       6.6         0.006       30          0.012   
15:24:52    0.004       8.1         0.012       3.5         0.006       16          0.012   
15:39:52    0.008       6.6         0.026       6.2         0.008       4.6         0.026   
15:54:52    0.009       6.6         0.022       8.5         0.006       28          0.023   
16:09:52    0.007       5.4         0.011       6.8         0.006       6.1         0.011   
16:24:52    0.003       51          0.011       2.4         0.006       47          0.011   
16:39:52    0.003       73          0.010       1.9         0.006       32          0.010   
16:54:52    0.003       >100        0.011       2.9         0.006       30          0.011   
16:59:59    0.003       37          0.010       2.3         0.005       10          0.010
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some notes you may find useful:
here a list of all the possible variables you can set in read_csv

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

particularly, I would recommand you to engage your attention on the commands "chunksize", which sets the number of default rows to be read and "transform" the df variable in a kind of pointer that provides you the right values only by using a for loop, as it follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathFile, chunksize = 20)

for chunk in df:
    print chunk
```

or you can use the "skiprows" and "nrows" variables as it follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathFile, skiprows = 40, nrows = 20 )
```

If you try to play around with these variables I believe you may be able to find the solution by yourself!